# Angular $http : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my first ever post in Stack Overflow. I am also returning to my programming roots after 16 years. Please pardon me if I am not following appropriate convention. I have been trying for more than a week to get the authentication API from iHealthLabs to work.

I am trying to process HTML that is returned by the iHealthLabs API. I need to process the HTML to make the [links clickable](http://intown.biz/2014/03/30/cordova-ionic-links-in-browser/) when the page is launched from the ngCordova [InAppBrowser](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) plugin (which is otherwise turned to plain text, I believe due to `$sanitize`). I am using Angular's `$http`.

In order for `$http` to not process the response as JSON, I have set the `transformResponse` option to `[]` as below:

```
var req = {
  url: "http://sandboxapi.ihealthlabs.com/OpenApiV2/OAuthv2/userauthorization/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&client_id=d9bc6644db6f4acfbf64748bac4782a1&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8100/ihealthdata?userid=john&APIName=OpenApiBP&RequiredAPIName=OpenApiBG+OpenApiBP&IsNew=true",
  method: 'jsonp',
  cache: false,
  transformResponse: []
};
```

Here is the request:

```
$http(req).
success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.html = data;

}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

However, I get the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I was wondering if there is something obvious I am missing or if I have to use the Angular Interceptors to trap the response and go from there.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suspect this in a simple syntax error with the example code above. Can you try changing your request from `$http(req).` to `$http.get(req).` and let me know if you get the same error?

Comment: @sal niro I tried this, but it gave me other errors. I believe the syntax is fine. Specifying `$http.get` or `$http(config)` where `var config = { {method:'GET'} }` creates the same object. Since the call is from a browser, it has to be JSONP otherwise I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.  So to follow your suggestion instead of `$http.get` , I used  `$http.json(req)` with the same result. I am getting the HTML back, but I think AngularJS is trying to process it as Javascript instead of HTML. Not sure if there is a way to tell AngularJS that the response is HTML.